# A more concise version of this Regular Expression?

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to match an integer or decimal number, followed by two dots `..`, followed by another integer or decimal number. On each side of the dots, the numbers are optional, but they *must* be present on one side or the other. I will be using Java for the actual implementation (`String#matches()`).

For example, these should match:

- `..12`
- `12..`
- `12..24`
- `12.23..14.25`

While these should not:

- `..`
- `foo`
- `foo..bar`
- `bazz12..12buzz`
- `foo11..22`
- `11..22efg`

This is the best I have been able to come up with:

```
(^(\d+\.?\d+)\.\.(\d+\.?\d+)?$)|(^(\d+\.?\d+)?\.\.(\d+\.?\d+)$)
```

I feel like it could be better. Am I wrong? Note that I have two clauses that are virtually the same with the pipe in the middle, the only difference is one matches `..12` and the other matches `12..`

Edit:
Thanks for all the input! I picked @anubhava because I asked for the shortest. Also thanks for pointing out the errors in my original expresion!

Comment: According to your description, `..` should match, but you give it as an example of something that shouldn't match. Also, does "integer or decimal number" allow for a sign? Exponential notation? Please be specific in what you're after. And which regex flavour is this?

Comment: Will update, that is a mistake in the question.

Comment: You rather might try to split on `..`, then match each side separately, and check literally whether one `||` the other is a number.

Comment: Do you consider `0.` and `.0` to be decimal numbers (as in Java)? I.e. should `.0...1` match? Also, your regexp maybe does not match `1..2`?

Comment: What about negative numbers, and scientific notation? `1e-4..1e4` is a shorthand for `0.0001..1000`.

Comment: Does the left side need to be smaller than the right (is `10..1` allowed)? Can one be decimal, the other integer (i.e. `1..1.1` allowed, or do you require `1.0..1.1`)? Do you intend to capture? Do you need to distinguish the integer vs. decimal cases?

Comment: One thing worth mentioning: If you're headed towards writing a tokenizer (lexer), you might want to have a look at [this link](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Lexer+grammar+for+floating+point%2C+dot%2C+range%2C+time+specs). Floating point plus ranges can be a challenge.

Comment: Note that with floating point, the parsing may not be unique... If you allow `1.` and `.1` (Java does!) then `1...1` could be either `1.`+`..`+`1` or `1`+`..`+`.1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a lookahead to shorten the regex:

```
^(?=\.*\d)(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?\.\.(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?$
```

Java regex:

```
Pattern p = 
        Pattern.compile("^(?=\\.*\\d)(?:\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)?\\.\\.(?:\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)?$");
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rV0zW7/1)

`(?=\.*\d)` is the positive lookahead that ensures there is at least one digit thus making sure we don't match just `..` as a valid input.

Comment: It is shorter, but not more efficient. See my answer for numbers.

Comment: @AustinHastings: The OP didn't say anything about efficiency, and how can that possibly matter anyway?  This answer is brilliant!  (But get rid of the slashes; this is Java, not JavaScript.)

Comment: @AlanMoore, the OP said "could be better". He was right, in that his own regex had at least one failure. But better also includes "faster," since regexes are usually used in parsing. Anu's answer is "cute," not "brilliant," since it solves the required-part problem, but requires a double-scan of the string. (Non-greedy lookahead might be faster - I'll try.)

Comment: @AustinHastings:  This answer fixes the error in the OP's regex, and performance is not an issue.  No one's parsing anything here; we're doing a simple, anchored match of a very short string.  As for the lookahead, it's never going to match more than a few characters; that's the brilliance of it.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to accept the answer, yesterday was a bear. I believe that based on my original question that this is the best answer, though I am also very happy to learn about the improvements in efficiency pointed out below.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this pattern that is not the shortest but more efficient and without useless things:

```
^(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?\.\.(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?|\.\.\d+(?:\.\d+)?)$
```

[test](http://fiddle.re/yzt6aa)

Notes:

Sometimes `\d` can match all unicode digits by default. To be more precise, you can replace all of them with `[0-9]` for a faster result (less characters to test).

If you use the `matches()` method (that seems logical in this case), the pattern is implicitly anchored, so you can write:

```
\d+(?:\.\d+)?\.\.(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?|\.\.\d+(?:\.\d+)?
```

---

If you want the shortest pattern you can write (perl, pcre, ruby, but not Java!):

```
^(\d+(\.\d+)?)?\.\.(?(1)(?1)?|(?1))$
```

It's short but inefficient.

Comment: Can you tell me why it is more efficient?

Comment: It won't match `..12`, probably you meant `^(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?\.\.(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?|\.\.\d+(?:\.\d+)?)$`

Comment: @eric: the anchors `^` and `$` are in factor, consequence they are tested only once. Using `(?:...)` instead of a capture group preserves memory. In the second branch I removed the first number (since if it is here, the first branch will succeed, no need to put it in the second branch).

Comment: This is all I like in a regex, powerful, but totally unmaintainable ;-)

Comment: @JérémieB: regexes are like any other language, once you understand them, it's easy to read and to edit. But if you want to do a good job, the best is to re(?:write|think) them.

Comment: Also regexps are often overused. If you are going to parse the data next anyway, you may as well split at `..` and then parse both sides as decimal if not empty.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse: in the present example it isn't a good idea since you don't know if the substrings on the left, on the right, or both, are an integer or a decimal number. When you use a pattern here, you check at the same time that there are on both side an empty string or a decimal or integer number.

Comment: Usually you can just always parse them as double; unless you really do not want to accept e.g. `1e0..1e2`

Comment: @Anony-Mousse: Indeed, and it is the case here.

Answer (score 2):

@Casimir is a surprisingly hard man to beat! I tried various permutations, and the only improvement I could come up with is one he made already - replacing `\d` with `[0-9]`. Here are some stats:

```
Author: OP, Len: 63, Memory: 784, Time: 0.9156907489523292
Author: Casimir, Len: 59, Memory: 544, Time: 0.7456484709400684
Author: Casimir0-9, Len: 77, Memory: 568, Time: 0.7377533189719543
Author: anubhava, Len: 51, Memory: 472, Time: 0.8746482610004023
```

**EDIT:** Updated with '1..2' test case, also extra-long cases, per suggestions in comments.

```
Author: Anony-Mousse, Len: 45, Memory: 456, Time: 1.3653777639847249
Author: Casimir, Len: 59, Memory: 544, Time: 1.1941137500107288
Author: anubhava, Len: 51, Memory: 472, Time: 1.5450064099859446
Author: OP, Len: 63, Memory: 784, Time: 1.82177433592733
Failed: should match '1..2'
Author: Casimir0-9, Len: 77, Memory: 568, Time: 1.1341593150282279
```

And here's how I tested:

```
import re
import sys
from timeit import timeit

Compiled_re = None
Failures = None

Should_match = (
    "1..2",          # EDIT: Updated per comments
    "..12",
    "12..",
    "12..24",
    "12.23..14.25",
    "123.456789012345..98765.43210",
)

Shouldnt_match = (
    "..",
    "foo",
    "foo..bar",
    "bazz12..12buzz",
    "foo11..22",
    "11..22efg",
    "123.456789012345..98765.43210.",
)

def test_re():

    cre = Compiled_re
    global Failures
    Failures = {}

    for test in Should_match:
        if cre.match(test) is not None:
            pass
        else:
            Failures[test] = "Failed: should match '{:s}'".format(test)

    for test in Shouldnt_match:
        if cre.match(test) is None:
            pass
        else:
            Failures[test] = "Failed: should not match '{:s}'".format(test)


candidates = {
    r"(^(\d+\.?\d+)\.\.(\d+\.?\d+)?$)|(^(\d+\.?\d+)?\.\.(\d+\.?\d+)$)":"OP",
    r"^(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?\.\.(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?|\.\.\d+(?:\.\d+)?)$":"Casimir",
    #r"^(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?\.\.(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?$":"dasblinkenlight",
    r"^(?=\.*\d)(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?\.\.(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?$":"anubhava",
    r"^(?:[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?\.\.(?:[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)?|\.\.[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)$":"Casimir0-9",
    r"^(?:\d+\.)?\d*(?:\d\.\.|\.\.\d)(?:\d+\.)?\d*$":"Anony-Mousse",
}

for pattern,author in candidates.items():
    Compiled_re = re.compile(pattern)
    length = len(pattern)
    mem = sys.getsizeof(Compiled_re)
    time = timeit('test_re()', setup='from __main__ import test_re',number=100000)
    print("Author: {author}, Len: {length}, Memory: {mem}, Time: {time}".format(
        author=author, length=length, mem=mem, time=time))
    if Failures:
        for test in Should_match + Shouldnt_match:
            if test in Failures:
                print(Failures[test])
```

Comment: Beware that Java re performance can be very different from python. Also add `1..2` to your tests.

Comment: The OP regex fails for 1..2, everyone else is fine.

Comment: Also add some long ones. like `123.456789012345..98765.43210` and should-fail `123.456789012345..98765.43210.` because of backtracking (which hurts much more in Java btw.)

Comment: Done. Why does backtracking cost so much more in Java?

Comment: Implementation of the regexp engine via recursion and backtracking as opposed to a state machine in other regexp engines. Thats why e.g. Googles RE2/J exists.

Answer (score 2):

Keep the alternatives short for efficiency.

```
^(?:\d+\.)?\d*(?:\d\.\.|\.\.\d)(?:\d+\.)?\d*$
```

Should do the trick, and not cause too much backtracking.

However, I don't think it is a good idea to **abuse regexps for parsing numbers**. They are not meant for this. For example, this may be a valid input for your pattern:

```
1.2345678901234567890..
```

but it exceeds double precision. There also is scientific notation: `1e-10..1e10` instead of `0.000000001..10000000000`. You still don't know if the left hand side is smaller than the right hand side.

I suggest you stick to doing this by 1. splitting at `..`, 2. parsing both sides using a well-tested double parser, 3. checking additional constraints such as at least one side being set and e.g. left<=right if both are set.

Comment: Not as fast as you might think. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Casimirs is very nice, indeed. Mine is shorter and used less memory in your benchmark.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a lookahead first to make sure the string isn't just `..`, then you can make both numbers optional and avoid the alternation:

```
^(?!\.\.$)(\d+(\.\d+)?)?\.\.(\d+(\.\d+)?)?$
```

As an aside, `(\d+\.?\d+)` requires that there be at least two digits, even if there's no decimal point.  Maybe that's okay in your case, but this way is more efficient as well.

As a rule, you want to avoid having adjacent parts of the regex that can match the same parts of the string.  When no match is possible, the regex engine will spend a ridiculous amount of time trying to match some of the digits with the first `\d+` and some with the second `\d+`, in every possible combination.